# Delay animated arcs with .attrTween method

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to create an animated arc diagram. I've been able to create the type of animation I want, but I would like to add a delay.

To create the animation I am using the .attrTween method.

This is the main portion of my code with my delay attempt:

```
svg.selectAll(".arcs")
      .data(data)
      .enter()
      .append("path")
      .style("stroke", "#832129")
      .attr("class", "arc")
      .attr("d", function(d){
        var To_scale = xScale(d.experience),
            From_scale = xScale(0),
            y = yScale(0),
            dx = To_scale - From_scale,
            dy = y,
            dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
        return "M" + From_scale + " " + y + " A 43 50 0 0 1 " + To_scale + " " + y;
      })
      .style("fill", "none")
      .style("opacity", 1)
      .call(transition)
      .on("mouseover",  function(d){
        var thisClass = d3.select(this).attr("class")
          d3.select(this).style("stroke", "white").style("opacity", 1)
          d3.selectAll(".arcs").style("opacity", 0.1)

        })
        .on("mouseout",  function(d){
          d3.select(this).style("stroke", "#832129").style("opacity", 1)
        })

// DELAY ATTEMPT HERE

function transition(path){
        path.transition()
          .delay(function(d, i){ return i * 1000})
          .duration(2500)
          .attrTween("stroke-dasharray", tweenDash)

      }

      function tweenDash(){
        var l = this.getTotalLength(),
            i = d3.interpolateString("0," + l, l + "," + l)
            return function(t){ return i(t); };
      }
```

The problem with this method is it just makes the chart appear with no delay or animation. I have also tried `.delay(100)`, but that just delays the animation.

I would like the delay/animation to look something like this https://twitter.com/sxywu/status/937510554310123520 where the arcs appear one after another. I am just confused as to why `.delay(function(d, i){ return i * 1000})` doesn't work.

My full code can be seen on my bl.ocks page here: https://bl.ocks.org/JulienAssouline/7236f0632102c6e2d3399208c4c90c26

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `opacity` to 0 for your arcs:

```
 svg.selectAll(".arcs")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("path")
  ...
  .style("opacity", 0) // <== !!!
  ...
```

And rewrite your `transition` function this way:

```
function transition(path){
  path.each(function(pathItem, index) {
    d3.select(this).transition()
    .delay(index + 200)
    .duration(index * 5 + 1000)
    .on('start',function() {
        d3.select(this).style("opacity", 1)
    })
    .attrTween("stroke-dasharray", tweenDash)
  })
}
```

Here we specify a transition parameters for every item in your selection separately. You can play with `delay` and `duration` values as you need.

Check [working example based on your code](https://jsfiddle.net/yfuLk9ew/2/). I hardcoded part of your csv data here (with the full dataset all paths will draw) to able to use jsFiddle, but all the other code the same.